# Как изменить цвет текста на кнопке python kivy?

Tags: python, button, kivy

сделал кнопку и на ней текст но цвет текста белый и не могу поменять,можно ли как то поменять цвет текста на кнопке в python kivy?Если можно то скажите как.Вот код:

Button:

```
font_name:'fonts/GillSans- 
BoldItalic.ttf'
text:'Кнопка'
                 
size_hint:None,None
size:456,90
```

Comment: Пробовали осуществлять поиск по этой теме?

Comment: Да конечно,даже в документации смотрел